# JScript function returning null when the code exists

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, master-pages

I have an asp.net c# website  that I am having a problem getting the jscript to execute. 
I have a masterpage that loads that contains the javascript and the code. A code excerpt is below.  When it runs, the timer never shows up.  If I click the close page button, I get an error that says:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: The value of the property 'closePage' is null or undefined, not a Function object.

on the line:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$CloseSection$btnClose" value="Close Page Now" onclick="closePage(); return false;" id="ctl00_CloseSection_btnClose" class="buttons" />
```

I have tried many things, moving the .js src line above and below the var section.  NOthing seems to change this.  The strange thing is this worked fine just a few days ago.  I noticed that MS made several VS updates on 9/14.

Any help would be appreciated.

I can do a view source and the js line shows up fine:

```
 <script src="jscripts/StoreFrontClose.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The source excerpt is below:

---

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CloseSection" runat="server">
 <script src="jscripts/PageClose.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  var timeoutMins = 0;
  var timeoutSecs = 30;
alert("getting ready to start timer");
if (source == "kiosk") {
  startPageCloseTimer();
}              
<div style="text-align: center;">
 The Page will close in: <span id="theTime" class="timeClass"></span>
    <br />
  <asp:Button ID="btnClose" CssClass="buttons" runat="server" OnClientClick="closePage();"
                        Text="Close Page Now" />
 <asp:Button ID="btnKeepOpen" CssClass="buttons" runat="server" OnClientClick="resetTimer();"
                        Text="Keep Page Open a little Longer" />
</div>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

---

the PageClose.js has:

```
    function startPageCloseTimer() {
    alertTimerId = setTimeout("AlertUser()", timeoutMilli);
    countDown();
}

function AlertUser() {
    extend = false;
    handleTimerId = setTimeout("HandleTimeout();", maxPopupTime);
    jQuery("#messagePopup").dialog("open");
}

function HandleTimeout() {
    if (!extend) {
        closePage();
    }
}

function KeepSessionAlive() {
    extend = true;
    resetTimer();
}



function resetTimer() {

    clearTimeout(alertTimerId);
    clearTimeout(handleTimerId);
    alertTimerId = setTimeout("AlertUser()", timeoutMilli);
    sec = timeoutSecs;
    min = timeoutMins;
    countDown();
}

function closePage() {
alert("getting ready to close page");
clearTimeout(handleTimerId);
clearTimeout(alertTimerId);
clearTimeout(countDownTimerId);
}

var sec = timeoutSecs; //   set the seconds
var min = timeoutMins; // set the minutes

function countDown() {
    sec--;
    if (sec == -01) {
        sec = 59;
        min = min - 1;
    } else {
        min = min;
    }
    if (sec <= 9) { sec = "0" + sec; }
    var time = "";
    if (min > 0) {
        time = (min <= 9 ? "0" + min : min) + " min and ";
    }

    time = time + sec + " sec ";

    if (document.getElementById("theTime")) {
        document.getElementById("theTime").innerHTML = time;
    }
    countDownTimerId = window.setTimeout("countDown();", 1000);
    if (min == '00' && sec == '00') {
        sec = "00";
        window.clearTimeout(countDownTimerId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing a closing script tag in the source excerpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot the closing `</script>` tag:

```
<script src="jscripts/PageClose.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var timeoutMins = 0;
    var timeoutSecs = 30;
    alert("getting ready to start timer");
    if (source == "kiosk") {
        startPageCloseTimer();
    } // end of script
</script> // close tag
```